editing an svg in blender then exporting to an stl
I'm trying to build a drawer using my CNC, no nails just glue and I need to convert to stl. The middle 2 panels have 4 horizontal cuts that span the gap between them and I would like the cuts to finish with the first of the 2 panels and then start up again with the next one.

Can it be done in Blender or is it easier on another software?
